# Send form data to local workstation to initiate a Photoshop script with parameters from data

Tags: javascript, php, json, forms

I have a large Photoshop script (written in Javascript) that accepts parameters from me and then generates unique software files and mockups to client specifications. What I would like to do is create a form on the company website for new clients to fill out and then when the form is submitted, have my Photoshop script execute automatically, thus eliminating the need for me to manually enter clients' custom parameters. What I am wondering is if it is at all possible to do this. I would need to somehow track the event as it goes to the server hosting the website and then relay that to my work station. Or, would I have to use my work station as the server (at least for the form)? 
I am hitting a wall when it comes to online research so if you don't have an answer, but perhaps have a keyword I have yet to google, that would be appreciated too! Thank you for your time spent reading this.

Details on the "parameters:" The data that needs to be sent consists of Strings and Numbers only. While it is impersonal and does not need encrytion, it could (in some cases) be way to long to fit using the GET method.

Side note: My most current research has lead me to investigate JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your problem :) , but if your problem is to transfer information from server to local machine for processing you can try :
1) store the submitted form on server in file or db, 
2) write another script on your local machine that will run every 10 minutes for example (you can do it via cron job in linux) which will grab the new inserted data from server and pass to your photoshop script or store in local machine.
Or you can do by nodejs, I mean
1) the script from local machine connects via socket to the server and listens for new events 
2) after each new substitution from website  the script receives data from socket and runs photoshop script with given parameters

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. Thank for listing a few of my options, I can take it from here!